# How to reference the node from within a custom SKAction Swift

Tags: swift, skaction

I can create a custom SKAction as follows:

```
extension SKAction {
  class func move(from: CGPoint, halfWayTo: CGPoint, duration: TimeInterval) -> SKAction {
    let midPoint = CGPoint(x: (from.x + halfWayTo.x)/2, y: (from.y + halfWayTo.y)/2 )
    return SKAction.move(to: midPoint, duration: duration)
  }
}
```

which I then use like this:

```
//Setup
let node = SKNode()
node.position = CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50)
let destination = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)

//Move from node's current position half way towards the destination
let action = SKAction.move(from: node.position, halfWayTo: destination, duration: 1)
node.run(action)
```

but in keeping with the standard:

```
SKAction.move(to: destination, duration: 1)
```

I would rather be able to say:

```
let action = SKAction.move(halfWayTo: destination, duration: 1)
node.run(action)
```

but I don't know how to refer to 'node' from inside the custom SKAction so that I can get it's position and calculate the halfway point?

Comment: I've been trying to do something similar, and I can't think of any way to do it. As you've realized, the `SKAction` has no access to the `SKNode` in question when you call `SKAction.move(halfwayTo:)`. Your extension to `SKNode` is an interesting idea, but I think I'll stick with an extension to `SKAction` and just pass the starting point, as you did in your original example. Seems better to make it clear in the code that we're creating an `SKAction`.

Comment: I agree that it's better as an extension to SKAction.

Answer (score 0):

You use `self`.

```
extension SKAction {
  class func move(halfWayTo: CGPoint, duration: TimeInterval) -> SKAction {
    let from = self.position
    let midPoint = CGPoint(x: (from.x + halfWayTo.x)/2, y: (from.y + halfWayTo.y)/2 )
    return SKAction.move(to: midPoint, duration: duration)
  }
}
```

Then call with (as you said)

```
node.move(halfWayTo: B, duration: 1)
```

Comment: Thanks very much TheValyreanGroup.

Comment: I've now tried out your suggestion. I get a compile error on the line "let from = self.position" saying: "Type 'SKAction' has no member 'position'

Comment: I've realised that my original question had syntax errors in it which implied that it was possible to do node.move but this was wrong.  It needs to be SKAction.move so I've edited my original question.

Comment: As @Adahus has pointed out, SKAction doesn't have a `position` member.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure whether the SKAction has a reference to the node it is applied to - even when it's running - or even if it does I'm not sure whether there's a way to access it. If anyone knows that it does please let me know.

I've thought of one approach as follows:

Instead of extending SKAction, extend SKNode as follows:

```
extension SKNode {
  func move(halfWayTo: CGPoint, duration: TimeInterval) -> SKAction {
    let from = self.position
    let midPoint = CGPoint(x: (from.x + halfWayTo.x)/2, y: (from.y + halfWayTo.y)/2 )
    return SKAction.move(to: midPoint, duration: duration)
  }
}
```

and then use as follows:

```
//Setup
let node = SKNode()
node.position = CGPoint(x: 50, y: 50)
let destination = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 100)

//Move from node's current position half way towards the destination
let action2 = node.move(halfWayTo: destination, duration: 1)
node.run(action2)
```